# C - binary tree: can't return correct number of pruned nodes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to prune a binary tree past a certain level, l and need to return the number of pruned nodes.

Here's what I got:

```
#include "abin.h"

int freeAB (ABin a) {
    int count = 0;
    if(a == NULL) return count;
    count = count + freeAB(a->esq);
    count = count + freeAB(a->dir);
    free(a);
    count++;
    return count;
}


int pruneAB (ABin *a, int l) {

    int count = 0;
    if(l == 0){
        count = count + freeAB((*a)->esq);
        count = count + freeAB((*a)->dir);
        (*a) = NULL;
    }
    else{
        count = count + pruneAB(&((*a)->esq), l-1);
        count = count + pruneAB(&((*a)->dir), l-1);
    }
    return count;
 }
```

**ABIN.H:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

typedef struct nodo {
    int valor;
    struct nodo *esq, *dir;
} *ABin;

int pruneAB (ABin *a, int l);
```

**This is the output of what I should have got and what I got:**

```
Input: (depth=2)
               8
       4              12
   2       6      10      14
 1   3   5   7   9  11  13  15

Output:
[expected] res=12
   8
 4  12

[obtained] res=8
   8
 4  12

0/10 correct answers
```

Interestingly, if I create something like int r = 0; and do r++; every time the if(l == 0) statement is true, and then do a print statement, it prints r 4 times.

If I added 4 to the final count I would get the correct answer. I assume that I should then add to count the number of times the if(l == 0) is true.

(I can't do it. If I do count++ I get segmentation fault)

How would you do it? Thanks.

https://codeboard.io/projects/16275

Comment: I suggest you use `gdb` to see where the `segmentation fault` occurs

Comment: If you get a crash (which is what a segmentation fault is) then you should run a debug-build in a debugger. When running in a debugger, it will catch crashes "in action" and stop execution at the location of the crash. Once stopped, you will be able to examine values of variables, and examine the function call stack, and even walk up the function call stack which you should do if the debugger stops in code that is not yours.

Comment: However, if you *don't* get a crash, you could still use a debugger. With a debugger, especially in an IDE, you can step through your code line by line, and step into your functions, to see what *really* happens. You will also be able to monitor your variables, and see how they change values.

Comment: Well, on this online compiler you are using ( CodeBoard ) there is no debugger available, so try to compile and debug the files locally with `gcc`,`msvc`,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int pruneAB (ABin *a, int l) {
    int count = 0;
    if (!*a) return 0;
    if (l < 0) return count;
    if(l == 0){
        count = freeAB(*a);
        (*a) = NULL;
    }
    else{
        count = count + pruneAB(&((*a)->esq), l-1);
        count = count + pruneAB(&((*a)->dir), l-1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think your solution is missing this to avoid a segmentation fault: `if(!*a) return 0;`   otherwise it looks like it's working, my mistake was that I  wasn't actually deleting one level off my binary tree, even though it appeared I did. Edit it so it's correct so I can mark it as best answer :) thanks.